# unix date comparison using if loop

Tags: unix, sh, unix-timestamp

Im not getting the output for this ... please help

```
now=$(date +"%T")
echo "Current time : $now"


if [ $now -gt '01:20:50' ]
then
echo "time is greater.. send mail to me"
else
echo "time is less.. send mail to all"

fi
```

Comment: what did you see on your screen? please provide more info about what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can not compare date formats directly in sh or bash with -gt / -lt. If you really want that, you can try [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/).

Otherwise, you should consider using the time format of seconds since epoch (seconds since Jan 1 1970 00:00:00) since this is integer. This could be done like this

```
now=$(date +"%T")
now_seconds=$(date +"%s")   #gives time in seconds since epoch
comparison_time=$(date -d '01:20:50' +"%s")
echo "Current time : $now"
echo "Current time : $now_seconds"
echo "Bench time : $comparison_time"

if [ $now_seconds -gt $comparison_time ]
then
    echo "time is greater.. send mail to me"
else
    echo "time is less.. send mail to all"
fi
```

Further, whether this works also depends on your shell, OS and especially your version of date. I verified that it works for bash 4.3.33 on Linux 4.0, date from GNU coreutils 8.23, but for instance not for FreeBSD 9.0, native date (since the -d option is defined differently there); there the respective line would have to be `comparison_time=$(date -j 0120.50 +"%s")`. There may be still other versions around.

Comment: You *could* compare them with `>`, though, since `%T` provides values that can be lexicographically ordered. `[ $now \> 01:20:50 ]` (With `[`, you need to escape `>` to prevent it from being considered a redirection operator.)

Comment: You are right, this works. And it actually works for both FreeBSD and Linux/ GNU coreutils.